# Looking to extract patterns from sequences of codes

Tags: python, uncertainty, pattern-recognition, sequential-analysis, information-retrieval

I have the following problem: I have a registration of people who enter a building, I have the name, entry date and end date. I also have the times at which events occur inside the building.

I want to find patterns on said data. To do that, I have constructed a python program in which, for an specific person, I get as rows the events which occurred during their stance inside the building as rows and ordered chronologically.

I am not sure on what statistical methodologies can be used to obtain information from this set of data.

I will leave a sample code to show what I have in case someone is curious.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data 
registrations_data = {
    "Names": ["Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Alice"],
    "Enter_Time": ["2023-11-28 13:34:40", "2023-11-28 14:00:00", "2023-11-28 15:30:00", "2023-11-29 10:00:00", "2023-11-30 10:00:00"],
    "Exit_Time": ["2023-11-28 14:30:00", "2023-11-28 15:00:00", "2023-11-28 17:00:00", "2023-11-29 12:00:00", "2023-11-30 12:00:00"]
}

events_data = {
    "Event_Code": ["E001", "E002", "E003", "E004", "E005", "E006", "E005B", "E002B"],
    "Event_Time": ["2023-11-28 13:45:00", "2023-11-28 14:15:00", "2023-11-28 16:00:00", "2023-11-29 11:00:00", "2023-11-29 11:30:00", "2023-11-29 11:30:20","2023-11-29 11:01:00", "2023-11-28 14:15:01"]
}

registrations = pd.DataFrame(registrations_data)
events = pd.DataFrame(events_data)

# Filter data for Alice
alice_data = registrations[registrations["Names"] == "Alice"]

# Create an empty list to store events for each visit
alice_events_list = []

# Iterate through each entry of Alice
for index, entry in alice_data.iterrows():
    # Filter events that occurred during the current entry
    entry_events = events[
        (events["Event_Time"] >= entry["Enter_Time"]) &
        (events["Event_Time"] <= entry["Exit_Time"])
    ]
    
    # Sort events chronologically
    entry_events = entry_events.sort_values(by="Event_Time")
    
    # Add the events to the list
    alice_events_list.append(entry_events["Event_Code"].tolist())

# Create a dataframe from the list
alice_events_df = pd.DataFrame(alice_events_list)

# Display the resulting dataframe for Alice
print(alice_events_df)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you want to do? Your analysis should be guided by the questions you want to have answered. Otherwise, you risk investing a lot of time in an analysis, only to find out afterwards that it answers an uninteresting question.

Comment: @stepah KoIassa mostly want to see which events repeat the most when someone is inside the building, e.g. when Amanda is inside, it is very normal to se E45 followed by E32 and then E14 or E01 and so on, or there are no events during Seth's stay